# jQuery iterate once on every click

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML table there are 2 fields (Number and Product) and a clickable text to add more 'Number' and 'Product' fields.

***Please check the below code snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var moreProducts = $('#MoreProducts');
  var extraProduct = $('<tr><td><label>Number: </label></td><td><input type="number" name="count' + i + '" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999"></td></tr><tr><td><label>Product: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="product' + i + '" maxlength="60"></td></tr>');

  moreProducts.click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      extraProduct.insertBefore('#MoreProductsFunction');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>Number:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="count" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999" required>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>Product:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="product" maxlength="60" required>*</td>
</tr>
<tr id="MoreProductsFunction">
  <td><a id="MoreProducts">Add more products...</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

For every click on #MoreProducts var extraProduct should be inserted once with unique name attribute (count0, count1, count2... and product0, product1...) before #MoreProductFunction. 
Why is my code not working and how should I do it?

PS: After I finished this, I've to grab all non-empty fields with PHP to add them in to a mail() function (maybe that's an important consideration in how to write this code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var moreProducts = $('#MoreProducts');

var i=0;
moreProducts.click(function(){
    if(i<20){  
      var extraProduct = $('<tr><td><label>Number: </label></td><td><input type="number" name="count'+ i +'" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999"></td></tr><tr><td><label>Product: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="product'+ i +'" maxlength="60"></td></tr>');
      extraProduct.insertBefore('#MoreProductsFunction');
      i++;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The ExtraProduct variable is using i before it's defined.

Try moving that definition into the loop;

```
moreProducts.click(function(){
    var extraProduct;
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        extraProduct = $('<tr><td><label>Number: </label></td><td><input type="number" name="count'+ i +'" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999"></td></tr><tr><td><label>Product: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="product'+ i +'" maxlength="60"></td></tr>');
        extraProduct.insertBefore('#MoreProductsFunction');
    }
```

Helping with your second point of only 1 insert per click:

```
var count = 0;

moreProducts.click(function(){
    count++;
    if(count < 20){
        var extraProduct;
            extraProduct = $('<tr><td><label>Number: </label></td><td><input type="number" name="count'+ count +'" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999"></td></tr><tr><td><label>Product: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="product'+ count +'" maxlength="60"></td></tr>');
            extraProduct.insertBefore('#MoreProductsFunction');
}
```

Comment: Also, I just saw your comment saying that you DON'T want all lines adding at once. If you want one addition per click, then remove the for loop, and add in some code to restrict the maximum number of times you can run insertBefore (possible count the number of times you have clicks, hold it in a variable, and make click fail when that count it above 20)

Comment: OK how can I iterate the 'i' after name=count?

Comment: Using the technique I mentioned above, hold the count of the number of times clicked in a global variable. That variable can be used in place of i.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you've beenn looking for :).

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xaewj3aL/7/

HTML (made it a bit more organized for you):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Number: </label></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="count" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999" required>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><label>Product: </label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="product" maxlength="60" required>*</td>      </tr>
   <tr id="MoreProductsFunction">
       <td><button id="MoreProducts">Add more products...</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var count = 0;

$('#MoreProducts').click(function() {
    var extraProduct = $('<tr><td><label>Number: </label></td><td><input type="number" name="count'+ count +'" maxlength="4" min="3" max="999"></td></tr><tr><td><label>Product: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="product'+ count +'" maxlength="60"></td></tr>');
    count++;
    extraProduct.insertBefore('#MoreProductsFunction');
});
```

So basically I've added a count outside of the loop (otherwise, the same numbers will appear as IDs).

Also, I had to declare the extraProduct in the click event, because you wanted the ID to vary by the count, right? :)
The ID number will increase over time.